# Store Image to the Public Folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

hello team help me I want to upload image to the "my-Project_folder/public/" but now uploaded to the "my-Project_folder/storage/app/" here is my config/filesystem

```
  'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

and my controller

```
 {
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        if ($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $request->file('image')->storeAs('images', $filename);
        }

        $creator = new Content_form([
            'media_id' => $request->get('media_name'),
            'content_title' => $request->get('content_title'),
            'content_description' => $request->get('content_description'),
            'date_occured' =>\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'),
            'page_number' => $request->get('page_number'),
            'image' => $filename,
        ]);
        $creator->save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   if ($request->hasFile('image')){
      $file = $request->file('image');
     $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // you can also use file name
     $fileName = time().'.'.$extension;
     $path = public_path().'/yourfolder';
     $uplaod = $file->move($path,$fileName);
     return $fileName;
   }
```

Comment: I put folder name but upload no where please assist

Comment: how to retrieve it in blade now saved to " public/images/.."

Comment: {{public_path().'/yourfolder/yourimagename'}}

Answer (score 0):

You are storing in Laravel's default storage path by doing this:

```
$request->file('image')->storeAs('images', $filename);
```

You have to specify the storage path or disk:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('image.jpg', $request->file('image'));
```

Comment: give me error: Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter::put(),